# inplace apply to columns of pandas dataframe satisfying conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

Consider the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': [1,2,3], 'x1': [4,5,6], 'x2': [7,8,9]} )

>>> print(df)
t  x1  x2
0  1   4   7
1  2   5   8
2  3   6   9
```

I would like to apply a function (say multiplying by 2) to those columns with names containing the character 'x'

This can be done by:

```
df.filter(regex='x').apply(lambda c: 2*c)
```

but not in place.  My solution is:

```
tmp = df.filter(regex='x')
tmp = tmp.apply(lambda c: 2*c)
tmp['t'] = df['t']
df = tmp
```

which has the added problem of changing the order of the columns.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I just up voted your question... you now have enough rep to vote yourself.  Feel free to up vote the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do something like this:

```
In [239]: df.apply(lambda x: x*2 if 'x' in x.name else x)
Out[239]:
   t  x1  x2
0  1   8  14
1  2  10  16
2  3  12  18
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [258]: df.apply(lambda x: x*2 if 'x' in x.name else x) \
            .rename(columns=lambda x: 'ytext_{}_moretext'.format(x[-1]) if 'x' in x else x)
Out[258]:
   t  ytext_1_moretext  ytext_2_moretext
0  1                 8                14
1  2                10                16
2  3                12                18
```

Comment: Great.  As a twist to the original problem, I also need to rename those columns containing 'x' such that for example 'x1' is renamed as 'ytext_1_moretext' and  'x2' is renamed as 'ytext_2_moretext'.  I know how to do this using regular expression subsitutions and df.rename(columns=lambda col: re.sub(...    Would that be the right way, or can even this selective column renaming be easily incorporated to your code?

Comment: Note that neither of the suggestions are really 'in-place' as requested by the OP. There is still an assignment `df = df.apply(...)` required.

Comment: @MaxU how to apply your method upto to a certain no of rows

Comment: @Naveen, please ask a new question, put there a small reproducible data set and your desired data set...

Comment: Unlike @piRSquared's answer, this does not present an inplace solution to the problem as asked by OP

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.columns.str.contains('x')` to get boolean mask to slice `df`

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('x')] *= 2
print(df)

   t  x1  x2
0  1   8  14
1  2  10  16
2  3  12  18
```

More generalized

```
def f(x):
    return 2 * x

m = df.columns.str.contains('x')
df.loc[:, m] = f(df.loc[:, m])
print(df)

   t  x1  x2
0  1   8  14
1  2  10  16
2  3  12  18
```

Using `apply`

```
m = df.columns.str.contains('x')
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].apply(f)
print(df)

   t  x1  x2
0  1   8  14
1  2  10  16
2  3  12  18
```