# Applying lambda to a dataframe but only upto to certain no of rows

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is like

```
a = {'A': {0: 40.1, 1: 40.1, 2: 40.1, 3: 45.45, 4: 41.6, 5: 39.6},
     'B': {0: 41.0, 1: 43.6, 2: 41.65, 3: 47.7, 4: 46.0, 5: 42.95},
     'C': {0: 826.0, 1: 835.0, 2: 815.0, 3: 169.5, 4: 170.0, 5: 165.5},
     'D': {0: 889.0, 1: 837.0, 2: 863.3, 3: 178.8, 4: 172.9, 5: 170.0}}

a = pd.DataFrame(a)

#a
       A      B      C      D
0  40.10  41.00  826.0  889.0
1  40.10  43.60  835.0  837.0
2  40.10  41.65  815.0  863.3
3  45.45  47.70  169.5  178.8
4  41.60  46.00  170.0  172.9
5  39.60  42.95  165.5  170.0
```

I want to divide columns C and D by 5 but only upto 2nd index

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43402677/6086913) I came up with

```
a.apply(lambda x: x/5 if 'C' in x.name or 'D' in x.name else x)
```

As you have thought, it applies on the whole column.

Any way to apply it only upto the 2nd index and keep them `inplace`

Comment: You mean up to and including index 2?

Comment: Yep, upto and including 2nd index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, to divide only columns `C` and `D` up to (and including) index 2, you can do:

```
a.iloc[:3][["C", "D"]] /= 5
```

Which results in:

```
       A      B      C       D
0  40.10  41.00  165.2  177.80
1  40.10  43.60  167.0  167.40
2  40.10  41.65  163.0  172.66
3  45.45  47.70  169.5  178.80
4  41.60  46.00  170.0  172.90
5  39.60  42.95  165.5  170.00
```

The above method is faster than using `apply`, but here is how to modify your existing code to get the same result:

```
a.iloc[:3] = a.iloc[:3].apply(lambda x: x/5 if x.name in {"C", "D"} else x)
```

The difference is that this runs the apply only on a slice of the DataFrame, and assigns the output back to the same slice.

Notice that we slice `[:3]` because the end index is not included in the slice. More on [understanding python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).

Also, you don't have to check both conditions individually- you can use `x.name in {..}` to check if `x.name` is contained in a set. Using a `set` to test membership is faster than using a `list`: [Python Sets vs Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2831242/5858851)
.

Answer (score 4):

For default index use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select:

```
a.loc[:2, ['C','D']] /= 5
```

**Detail**:

```
print (a.loc[:2, ['C','D']])
       C      D
0  826.0  889.0
1  835.0  837.0
2  815.0  863.3
```

General solution for all index values (e.g. `DatetimeIndex`) use [`get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for positions by columns names and [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select:

```
a.iloc[:3, a.columns.get_indexer(['C','D'])] /= 5
print (a)
       A      B      C       D
0  40.10  41.00  165.2  177.80
1  40.10  43.60  167.0  167.40
2  40.10  41.65  163.0  172.66
3  45.45  47.70  169.5  178.80
4  41.60  46.00  170.0  172.90
5  39.60  42.95  165.5  170.00
```

**Detail**:

```
print (a.iloc[:3, a.columns.get_indexer(['C','D'])])
       C      D
0  826.0  889.0
1  835.0  837.0
2  815.0  863.3
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but isn't OP asking for `a.iloc[:2][["C", "D"]] /= 5`? *"I want to divide columns C and D by 5 but only upto 2nd index"*

Comment: Yep, only upto the 2nd index